# How to "teach" TensorFlow to compute expected output?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

So as a fun project, I've been messing with the TensorFlow API (in Java unfortunately.. but I should be able to get some results out anyways). My first goal is to develop a model for 2D point cloud filtering. So I have written code that generates random clouds in 224x172 resolution, computes the result of a neighbor density filter, and stores both (see images below).
[image]

[image]

So basically I have generated data for both an input and expected output, which can be done as much as needed for a massive dataset.

I have both the input and output arrays stored as 224x172 binary arrays (0 for no point at index, 1 for a point at that index). So my input and output are both 224x172. At this point, I'm not sure how to translate my input to my expected result. I'm not sure how to weight each "pixel" of my cloud, or how to "teach" the program the expected result. Any suggestions/guidance on whether this is even possible for my given scenario would be appreciated!

Please don't be too hard on me... I'm a complete noob when it comes to machine learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine, that Tensorflow is a set of building blocks (like LEGO) that allows constructing machine learning models. After the model is constructed, it could be trained and evaluated.
So basically your question could be divided into three steps:
1. I'm new to machine learning. Please guide me how to choose the model that fits the task.
2. I'm new to tensorflow. I have the idea of model (see 1) and I want to construct it via Tensorflow.
3. I'm new to Java's API of tensorflow. I know how to build model using tensorflow (2), but I'm stuck in Java. 
This sounds scaring, but that's not too bad really.
 And I'd suggest you the following plan  to do: 
1. You need to look through the machine learning models to find the model that suits your case. So you need to ask yourself: what are the models that could be used for cloud filtering? 
 And basically, do you really need some machine learning model? Why don't you use simple math formulas?
That are the questions you may ask to yourself. 
Ok, assume you've found some model. For example, you've found a paper describing neural network able to solve your tasks. Then go to the next step 
2. Tensorflow has a lot of examples and code snippets. So you could even 
find the code with your model implemented yet. 
The bad thing, that most code examples and API are Python based. 
 But as you want to go into machine learning, I'd suggest you studying Python. It's easy to enter. It's very common to use python in the science world as it allows not to waste time on wrappers, configuration, etc. (as Java needs). We just start solving our task from the first line of the script. 
As I've told initially about tensorflow and LEGO similarity, I'd like to add that there are more high-level additions to the tensorflow. So you work with the not building blocks but some kind of layers of blocks. 
Something like [tflearn](http://tflearn.org/tutorials/quickstart.html). It's very good especially if you don't have deep math or machine learning background. It allows building machine learning models in a very simple and understandable way. So do you need to add some neural network layer? Here you are. And that's all without complex low-level tensor operations. 
The disadvantage that you won't be able to load tflearn model from Java. 
Anyway, we assume, at the end of this step you are able to build your model, to train it and to evaluate the model and prediction quality.
3. So you have your machine learning model, you understand Tensorflow mechanics, and if you still need to work with Java that should be much easier yet.
I note, that you won't be able to load tflearn model from Java.  You can try to use jython to call python's functions directly from Java, though I haven't tried it.
And on this way (1-3) you will definitely have some more questions. So welcome to SO.